# How do I reach variables in a chrome extension popup localStorage from content scripts?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have stored some options in my chrome extension. Using localStorage.setItem().

But when I want to use them on a page, it's not working. I know it's because they are totally in different domains, but how can I reach the settings in my chrome extension domain from any other domain (in my page scripts).

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `chrome.storage` API.

To save something locally:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({"key":"value"});
```

To retrieve a value:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("key",function(res) {
console.log(res[key])
});
```

If you don't want the storage to sync across the user's account, you can use `chrome.storage.local` instead of `chrome.storage.sync`

[Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)

Answer (score 3):

Use of `localStorage` inside the extension's domain is *very* old style and should not be done nowadays.

Extensions have [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) for this purpose; it's shared between the extension context and content script contexts.

Note, though, that it's inherently asynchronous.

If you use `sync` storage, you get replication between extension installs of the same user as a free bonus.

The legacy way to deal with it is with [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging): your background page can expose get/set methods over it. However, it's still asynchronous to talk between contexts. Spare yourself the complexity and use `chrome.storage`.